# How come SSH over USB is Wifi dependant?

Tags: wifi, usb, ssh, raspbian-stretch, pi-zero-w

As stupid as it sounds, here is the case:

tl;dr: ssh via wifi into Rpi works. ssh via usb works as well, but only when Rpi is connected to wifi. Why?

Imagine we have a Raspberry Pi Zero W working in headless mode running the latest Raspbian Stretch, up to date and all. Said Rpi has two modes of ssh manually established on it - USB (per instructions in `Video_1`) and Wifi.

Here's the funky bit - ssh over USB seems to be wifi dependant. Meaning, it is possible to establish an ssh connection via a usb cable and work normally (`ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` allows you to connect to the Rpi) when the pi is connected to wifi. Pull the plug on the router, and the USB connection is disabled - and you cannot work through it anymore.

What might be causing this? Is it possible to make sure that the two ssh connections - USB and Wifi - are independent?
Could one even ssh into a Rpi via USB without the Rpi being connected any other network, such as on an airplane?

**Current configuration:**

Board: Raspberry Pi Zero W, headless

OS: Raspbian Stretch with desktop, version April 2018

Modifications made:

1. Added a file named `ssh` to boot
2. Added `dtoverlay=dwc2` to the end of *config.txt*
3. Added `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` to *cmdline.txt* after `rootwait` argument
4. Added static IP assignments of gateway and Pi to the end of *dhcpcd.conf*
5. Added network information (ssid, password) to *wpa_supplicant.conf*

`Video_1`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xj3MPmJhAPU&t=188s

**Solved:**
The issue can be solved on Linux Ubuntu by changing the incoming Ethernet connection IPv4 parameters to Link-local-only

Comment: Do you connect your pc with an USB cable to an USB port on the raspi? How do you establish an ethernet connection for TCP to use for `ssh` through an USB cable? What are your modifications to `cmdline.txt` and `config.txt` to realize this?

Comment: perhaps the raspberry pi needs an IP address to communicate over TCP/IP protocol used by SSH

Comment: Hi Ingo, to the end of config.txt I add `dtoverlay=dwc2`, and to cmdline.txt I add modules-load=dwc2,g_ether as an argument after rootwait.
Also, Jaromanda, I append static IP's to dhcpcd.conf, which seems enough for Wifi ssh

Comment: I use ssh via a USB OTG connection with a Zero and no other networking, so it is not impossible ;)  Probably you should include some more details about your configuration.

Comment: Edited, thanks for the heads up! Anything you think I missed?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: There's no error message - the ssh just doesn't connect if the Wifi is off: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi.local: Name or service not known`... And even if it is connected via USB, if the router is disconnected the USB connection fails

Comment: Hi Fabian, edited the question like you asked - thanks for pointing out the unclear bits!
This is the new paragraph:
*Here's the funky bit - ssh over USB seems to be wifi dependant. Meaning, it is possible to establish an ssh connection via a USB cable and work normally (`ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` allows you to connect to the Rpi) when the pi is connected to wifi. Pull the plug on the router, and the USB connection is disabled - and you cannot work through it anymore.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know for sure, but I'm guessing that it could be something to do with the WiFi being a USB device (as is the Ethernet I/O). My guess is turning off the WiFi is disconnecting or powering down the USB hub chip?

Comment: Could be, but it's a Raspberry pi Zero W - the wifi has it's own antenna and location on it, right?